# add multiple values to key in hashtable

Tags: java, hashmap

I need help with adding description to *roomType* in code below. Now I can add only one word to *roomType*, but i want to be able to add multiple words such as *"double suite room"*.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<String, String> rooms = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String roomNumber = "0";
    String roomType = null;
    System.out.println( "Enter room numbers and type : [ Enter  'stop' to quit ]" );

    while(!roomNumber.equals("stop")){
        input.useDelimiter(", *");
        roomNumber = input.next();

        if(roomNumber.equals("stop")){
            break;
        }
        roomType = input.next();

        rooms.put(roomNumber, roomType);
    }
```

I also tried this approach:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> rooms = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> roomTypeList= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> description= new ArrayList<String>();

    String roomNumber = "0";
    String roomType = null;
    System.out.println( "Enter room numbers and type : [ Enter  'stop' to quit ]" );

    while(!roomNumber.equals("stop")){
        roomNumber = input.next();

        if(roomNumber.equals("stop")){
            break;
        }
        roomType = input.next();
        description.add(roomType);
        rooms.put(roomNumber, description);
    }
```

But scanner is not working properly this way.
Thanks
P.S. also any other remarks are welcome

Comment: I think, guava's Multimaps will help you. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: I think the "value" in your map should be some object, rather than a `String`.  The object would hold both the "room type" and a description.  From what I can see, you're not mapping the room number to two strings equally; rather, your two strings have two different purposes, so a multimap or a `Map<String,List<String>>` wouldn't be an appropriate solution.

Comment: @emily do you get any error?

Comment: @KickButtowski no i get no errors

Comment: @Emily why do not you follow what ajb said? so you can be more organized

Comment: @Emily your room type is type integer why you try to compare that with "stop"? does not make sense?

Comment: @KickButtowski it's a string since roomNumber can be 103A for example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to change the scanners default delimiter from a space to something like comma space.

```
// Set delimiters to space and comma.
//  ", *" tells Scanner to match a comma and zero or more spaces as
// delimiters.
input.useDelimiter(", *");
```

Right now, when you enter "double suite room" next should pick up double, then when called again will pick up suite etc.. by altering the delimiter to "," you can enter as many spaces as you like until you hit a comma, then it will stop accepting input.

Make sense?

Comment: yes, it makes sense and my second implementations behaves exactly the way you described, however delimiter did not solve my issue, but thanks for response.

Comment: Have you tried debugging by printing out the variables after .next() has run so that you can see how it is behaving when you are using your desired inputs? For the sake of clarity you want to put two values into the map, key="13" value="double suite room", key="28" value="single standard room". Correct? If that is the case there is no reason to use an object and you are using the correct data structure, the problem most likely lies in debugging the input method, which can be confusing at times.

Comment: So I just ran the first version with some added print statements and got some funny output. double
#=1 Type=double
suite
room
#=suite Type=room
3
3
balmy heck hole
balmy
#=3 Type=balmy
heck
hole
#=heck Type=hole
stop
stop

Comment: As you can see above, the roomType variable is being space delimited and taking only the last value from whatever is entered. If you change the delimiter that will solve your problem efficiently.

Comment: I have edited first version, please check is it what you mean? If yes, then I cannot exit the while loop for some reason.

Comment: Enter room numbers and type : [ Enter  'stop' to quit ]
3, double suite room, 13, single standard, stop
3
 double suite room
#=3 Type= double suite room
 13
 single standard
#= 13 Type= single standard
,
 stop

Comment: above used "input.useDelimiter(",");" then instead of roomNumber.equals I used roomNumber.contains("stop"); That worked, just remember that you'll have to comma separate your inputs i.e. 3, suite double room, 12, standard single, stop,

Comment: Enter room numbers and type : [ Enter  'stop' to quit ]
3, suite double room, 123, standard single, stop,
RN=3
 suite double room
#=3 Type= suite double room
RN= 123
 standard single
#= 123 Type= standard single
RN= stop

Comment: as you can see I put a comma after stop, Scanner delimited by comma, discarded the comma, and roomNumber became 'stop'

Comment: btw until it reached the comma after stop it was still waiting for input which is why the variable wasn't assigned stop and the loop did not exit

Comment: you need to change the change you made. input.useDelimiter(","); using just a comma instead of input.useDelimiter(", *");

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of description you want to use but i'd wrap the type and the description in some object/enum.

Perhaps something like

```
public enum RoomType {
    SOME_ROOM_TYPE("description of first type"),
    SOME_OTHER_TYPE("description of other type");

    String description;

    public RoomType(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    } 

    public static RoomType convert(String original) {
         // some code for converting the string from the scanner, 
         // maybe Enum.valueOf(...)
    }
}
```

And then in your scanner loop:

```
rooms.put(roomNumber, RoomType.convert(description));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `MultiValueMap` class from the Apache Commons [Collections library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections).

```
// create multimap to store key and values
MultiMap multiMap = new MultiValueMap();

// put multiple values for "key" 
multiMap.put("key", "Apple");
multiMap.put("key", "Aeroplane");
multiMap.put("key", "Hello World");
```